# Storing and updating a byte repeatedly without wearing the EEPROM of a smartcard

Tags: smartcard

I would like to manage a one-byte counter which increments everytime a specific command is sent to the smartcard. This counter will always be reset to 0 after reaching 255.

Is there another way to manage this counter without eventually wearing the card due to excessive EEPROM writes? Would it be possible to compute/store this counter without using the EEPROM?

Comment: How often do you need to update within the comlete card life cycle? Is it necessary for EVERY update to survive the session or just special ones?

Comment: The counter will be updated at least 1,000 times a day until card becomes unusable due to wearing. No, it is not necessary for every update to survive the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store this counter on device that reads your cards based on some unique id.

Or you can use multiple bytes for storing one byte so it doesn't wear up as fast.
Example implementation would be to first have all zeroes, then updating first byte to 1 then next to 2 and when reading you can use only biggest. When you have to reset you would reset all bytes to zero.

Example with four bytes:

1. 0-0-0-0
2. 1-0-0-0
3. 1-2-0-0
4. 1-2-3-0
5. 1-2-3-4
6. 5-2-3-4
7. ...
8. 252-253-254-255
9. 0-0-0-0

Notice that every write only modifies one byte except for the reset.

Comment: Thanks. This solution is helpful but EEPROM wearing is still unavoidable. I guess there is no exact solution for my problem.

Comment: I'm not convinced of the proposed solution in all cases. Currently used flash technology updates in units of pages, which depending on the chip consists of 16 bytes or more, so there would be no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a problem, to replace the card every year, there is no need for any special handling, since 500.000 write accesses are supported by some hardware manufacturers. In any case run the update process on a real sample card up to wear-out, to find out real limit.

Otherwise you may attempt the following:

- The write process to your counter probably needs an access right.
  Make sure, that this right is acquired only once per session
  (otherwise the most beautiful scheme will not improve anything).
- Try to reduce real updating processes, e. g. by retrieving the
  counter value at the beginning of the session and update a RAM copy
  (within your host application) and write through to non-volatile
  memory only every 10, 100 or other sensible intervals. If this is
  still not sufficient, try to distribute the information within a big
  file, where big means substantially larger than the page size, so you
  are sure to really address different memory pages.